# Work of a force

Tags: classical-mechanics, work

What does the work of a force really represent ? Isn't there any good explanations describing the idea behind this notion, when I first saw it, it felt like the work is equal to the force vector doted with the distance vector because the teacher said so. I'm sorry if my question is unusual or not worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kinetic energy theorem gives a good way to understand work. Applying a force on an object changes its velocity, thus it's kinetic energy. Then, its kinetic energy's variation is equal to the work of the force.

You can "understand" why we define work by $\delta W=\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dl}$ with some particular cases: the best way to accelerate an object is to apply a force on the direction of motion, while pushing it perpendicularly only curves its path.